# How can I make WPF app to work on a web browser

Tags: wpf, webassembly, winui-3

We have an existing application written in WPF and we our looking for a way to migrate it so it will work on web browsers.

After digging up, it seems that we need to find a way to compile the code to webassembly, but I'm not sure how good it will work for an existing fully loaded WPF app.

Any idea on how to start?

Comment: you mean silverlight?

Comment: There is no way to run WPF applications in modern web browsers. There was [XBAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-xaml-browser-applications-overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) but its not widely supported nor recommended. If you want to develop web applications, WPF is not the framework to use.

Comment: Uno Platform is probably closest to what you are looking for.  Depending on the complexity of your WPF app, it might be worth a look.

Comment: Should also mention cshtml5 which does something similar

Answer (score 3):

[Uno Platform](https://platform.uno) could definitely help you port your applications to any browser using WebAssembly. The ability to do it depends on the way your WPF application is developed:

- Are you accessing platform features through *Interop* or advanced libraries?
- Are you using advanced XAML features only available in WPF? (MultiBinding, event trigger...)
- Are you accessing network services directly, like an SQL server? (When running in a browser, you're subject to its security limitations like any *web app*)
  So, if your application is pretty self-contained or already accessing its external dependencies using http APIs, the migration to Uno should be straightforward.

You can try the *get started* on Uno at the following link: https://platform.uno/wpf/

Disclaimer: I'm working for Uno Platform.