# Call C# DLL FROM Frontend

Tags: c#, reactjs, dll

I need to call C# DLL (WPF application built using .NET) from ReactJS.

1. I saw on one of the forums that we can use DLLExport in c# and use 'require' to import the DLL in NodeJS. I tried the same for my ReactJS app. But get error "require is not defined and have trouble resolving it for ReactJS. Please find the below link that I used as reference to make use of DLLExport and require.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN5NXDtOuek

2. It was specified in the below forum that EdgeJS can be used as a bridge between NodeJS V8 and C# CLR. But haven't tried yet.

[Call Function from DLL loaded in front-end javascript (load dll in clientside javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791334/call-function-from-dll-loaded-in-front-end-javascript-load-dll-in-clientside-ja)

Now, I wonder if I am using the right approach. Can NodeJS sample be used as reference to make ReactJS call DLL, as NodeJS is server side.

I would appreciate any pointers on this or kindly refer any material or documentation(for calling c# dll from reactJS). Thank you.

Comment: I have a feeling your solution is going to be NOT calling a dll from React. If you describe what you are trying to accomplish maybe there is a much more straightforward way.

Comment: @Crowcoder No, I want to call the C# dll (created using WPF with .NET) from ReactJS. The label printer dll that is created by c#,  basically generates and prints QR code on labels. We want to use those functionalities in ReactJS (by calling dll). Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Maybe if you took the code out of the WPF app and were able to compile it to webassembly.... I am confident you can generate qr codes and print them from javascript. Trying to re-use your WPF app in this way will be an exercise in frustration.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me further. Is it because server side dll can't be run on client browser (ReactJS) ? whereas webassembly can be run on client browser if I am not wrong.

Comment: Basically yes, it is because a browser cannot natively understand anything other than javascript or webassembly. Maybe [this would be of interest to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729887/how-can-i-make-wpf-app-to-work-on-a-web-browser)

Comment: Blazor javascript interop is typically how you would achieve this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: If JS running in a browser was able to call into a local DLL we'd all be in a world of hurt. This is why the browser sandbox exists.